# Tinymce image upload handler optimization

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have written an image upload script for tinymce, but was wondering if it could be optimized in any way? It seems to work pretty well, but I believe there is room for improvements. How it works is pretty simple, png, jpeg, jpg, bmp are all resized to 800px x 800px if they have larger dimensions. I found gifs were more problematic to work with, so instead of resizing them I thought it would be best to limit the file size which could be uploaded instead, then allow the original file to be uploaded.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea#comment',
    plugins: 'media preview link emoticons help insertdatetime table anchor wordcount visualblocks image code',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | media | image | blocks | ' + 'bold italic backcolor forecolor | alignleft aligncenter ' + 'alignright alignjustify | outdent indent removeformat',
    content_css: '/css/styling.css',
    media_live_embeds: true,
    media_poster: false,
  menu: {
    file:  { title: 'File', items: 'print' },
    edit:  { title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall' },
    view: { title: 'View', items: 'visualaid  visualblocks preview wordcount code' },
    insert: { title: 'Insert', items: 'table inserttable | cell row column | advtablesort | tableprops deletetable | emoticons link anchor media image | hr | insertdatetime' },
    format: { title: 'Format', items: 'bold italic underline strikethrough | styles blocks fontfamily fontsize align lineheight | forecolor backcolor | removeformat' },
    table: { title: '', items: '' },
    tools: { title: '', items: '' },
    help:  { title: 'Help', items: 'help' },
  }, 
    block_unsupported_drop: true,
    paste_data_images:false,
    image_title: true,
    images_file_types: 'jpg,png,gif,jpeg',
    file_picker_types: 'image',
    file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
        input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
        input.setAttribute('name', 'photos');
        input.addEventListener("change", (event) =>  {
            let FILE = event.target.files[0];
            var fTypes = ["jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg", "bmp"];
            filename = FILE.name.substring(FILE.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, FILE.name.length) || FILE.name;
            if (fTypes.indexOf(filename) == 2) {
                var fileSizeLimit = 0.1;
                if (FILE.size > fileSizeLimit * 1024 * 1024) {
                    alert(" Error! Image is too large, maximum file size allowed is 100kb");
                    return null;
                }
            }
            if (fTypes.indexOf(filename) > -1) {
                let reader = new FileReader;
                reader.readAsDataURL(FILE);
                reader.onload = (event) => {
                    let image_url = event.target.result;
                    let image = document.createElement("img");
                    image.src = image_url;
                    image.onload = (e) =>  {
                        var MAX_WIDTH = 800;
                        var MAX_HEIGHT = 800;
                        var width = e.target.width;
                        var height = e.target.height;
                        if (width > height) {
                            if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                                height = height * (MAX_WIDTH / width);
                                width = MAX_WIDTH;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                                width = width * (MAX_HEIGHT / height);
                                height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                            }
                        }
                        let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                        canvas.width = width;
                        canvas.height = height;
                        const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                        let new_image_url = context.canvas.toDataURL();
                        let new_image = document.createElement("img");
                        new_image.src = new_image_url;
                        doBlob();
                        async function doBlob() {
                            const base64Response = await fetch(new_image.src);
                            const blob = await base64Response.blob();
                            let obj = '';
                            if (fTypes.indexOf(filename) == 2) {
                                obj = FILE;
                            }else{
                                obj = blob;
                            }
                            var id = 'xxxblobid' + (new Date()).getTime();
                            var blobCache = tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                            var base64 = new_image.src.split(',')[1];
                            var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, obj, base64);
                            blobCache.add(blobInfo);        
                            cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), {
                                title: FILE.name,
                                imageSize: canvas.width * canvas.height,
                                maxSize: canvas.width * canvas.height
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                alert('Sorry, we only allow, jpg, png, gif or jpeg files, Please choose another file to upload.');
                return null;
            }
        });
        input.click();
    },
    content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
});
```

I am sure this code could be improved for better performance. This is my first attempt at meddling with tinymce's editors because I could not find a good image upload script for it.